# Como mostrar bootstrap popover solo cuando la celda tenga un valor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables, bootstrap-3

Tengo una tabla de boostrap en la cual en una celda del cada row podria cargar el valor de un array convertido a base 64, digo podria porque aveces la propiedad que mapea ese valor podria venir en  null:

```
    <table id="tableOcMateriales" class="table table-condensed  table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables_length" style="width: 100%; align-content: center">
    <thead class="ColorHeaderTable">
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 20%">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MaterialDescripcion)
            </th>
            <th style="display: none"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="celda">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr data-toggle="popover">
                <td style="width: 20%">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MaterialDescripcion)
                </td>
                <td style="display: none">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImagenB64)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Estoy tratando de mostrar la imagen en un popover cuando el usuario haga click en el row del Table, para eso estoy usando este script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#tableOcMateriales').on('click', 'tbody tr', function (event) {
        var img;
        if (!$(this).closest('tr').find('td').hasClass('dataTables_empty')) {

            $(this).addClass('highlightchecked').siblings().removeClass('highlightchecked');

            var imagenBase64 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(7)').text();
            if (imagenBase64 !== "") {
                img = '<div id ="image"><img src ="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imagenBase64 + '\" style="width:370px;"/></div>"';
            }
            else {
                img = '';
            }
        }

        if (img !== "") {
            var closebtn = $('<button/>', {
                type: "button",
                text: 'X',
                id: 'close-preview',
                style: 'font-size: initial;'
            });

            closebtn.attr("class", "close pull-right");

            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                trigger: 'focus',
                container: '.modal-body',
                placement: 'auto',
                title: "<strong>Preview</strong>" + $(closebtn)[0].outerHTML,
                content: img,
                html: true
            }).popover('show').not(this).popover('hide');

        }

        $('body').on('click', '#close-preview', function (e) {

            $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover('hide');
        });

    });
});
```

Con el script anterior logro mostrar el popover pero me muestra la misma imagen en todos los rows, **quiero que si el row no contiene el valor de imagen no me muestre el popover**.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno formas para solucionar al tema supongo que hay muchas pero si le pones la propiedad a un clase no es más facil, por ejemplo puedes poner la clase solo a los tr que cumple tu condición entonces el código cambiaria por el siguiente;

```
 $('#tableOcMateriales').on('click', 'tr.alguna-clase', function (event) {
    ...
    ...
 });
```

ahora si este paso no se puede hacer la condicion para validar el contenido del td seria la siguiente;

```
if( $(this).find("li:eq(1)").html() != ''){
...
...
}
```

espero te pueda ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Creo que si en lugar de poner el evento a ese row, porque no anclas el evento .on('click'...) a una clase que solo le pongas a la celda con imagen, algo como:

```
var myClass;

if (hasImagen(current_row)) {
  myClass = 'hasImageClass';
} else {
  myClass = '';
}
```

y cuando pintes el row haces un

```
<tr class="<% myClass; %>"...
```

y eso solo escribirá cuando tengas imagen.

Con eso ya solo tienes los rows con la clase de 'hasImageClass' ahora puedes anclar el evento click a esta clase.

Saludos!